# How to publish using msbuild

Tags: .net, asp.net, msbuild

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I publish a Asp.net web application using MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550/how-do-i-publish-a-asp-net-web-application-using-msbuild)

I have a web application and I want to publish it using msbuild.

I am not interested in the copying files part I just want a directory of files that do not have cs files and and contain the same files as the publish directory would.

I tried using AspNetCompiler, but I am getting extra files in the bin directory:

App_global.asax.compiled

App_global.asax.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looked this up just a few days ago :)

http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/18/how-to-publish-a-web-site-with-msbuild/

Answer (score 0):

I had to use aspnet_merge to get rid of the app_global.asax.dll