# writing msbuild script

Tags: .net, asp.net, msbuild

please provide me BASIC steps how to write msbuild script to automate build process for asp.net website project hosted in svn server. (which will do labeling etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**General part:**

1. [Best Practices For Creating Reliable Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx).
2. [THE CUSTOM MSBUILD TASK COOKBOOK](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/15/the-custom-msbuild-task-cookbook.aspx) from Bart De Smet

**ASP.NET part:**

1. [Building with MSBUILD](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/78/building-with-msbuild/)
2. [How do I publish a Asp.net web application using MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550/how-do-i-publish-a-asp-net-web-application-using-msbuild)
3. [Continious Integration](http://omaralzabir.com/asp_net_website_continuous_integration_deployment_using_cruisecontrol_net__subversion__msbuild_and_robocopy/)
4. [Automating ASP.NET Web Application Project Build Using CruiseControl.Net and MSBuild](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/webappccnetmsbuild.aspx)

Comment: +1 maybe not what the OP expected but a very useful collection.