# How to publish Asp.net Web Application from a Web Service or Windows Form App(Not from Vs editor)

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, publishing, dynamic-programming

I am working on a project and we need to deploy our web projects to server but these web projects are creating dynamically by end users. so we gather all files of web project in a file. finally we need to push these files to server with publish. but how can i do without VS editor's manual publish option. do u have any website or any source that example to my aim, or  if you know sth about it can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio in command line mode to do the same but assuming that you probably do not have access to VS on, your next bet would be [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx).

See these links that tells how to use MSBuild to publish a web project:

http://blog.m.jedynak.pl/2008/03/publishing-web-application-with-msbuild.html
[How do I publish a Asp.NET web application using MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550/how-do-i-publish-a-asp-net-web-application-using-msbuild)